# matlab-prettifier with fancyvrb-style of label / frame

Tags: listings, code, sourcecode, matlab, fancyvrb

I wonder how to make the frame line around caption of listing not being printed (top line being broken into two by caption in the middle) when matlab-prettifier (or listings package) are being used, just like fancyvrb package:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

I have been reading the documents of matlab-prettifier and listings, and do not quite understand the interface between listings and fancyvrb. I can only find a solution for minted package:

[Minted with fancyvrb label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8246/minted-with-fancyvrb-label)

Here is a MATLAB code demonstration MWE, only for convenience to you guys doing copy and paste as an example to improve. This example is with line number and frame:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style = Matlab-editor, caption = {My 1st Code}, label = first]
% a comment
clear all, clc

x = [1.00; 1.00; 1.00];
beta0 = [1 1 1];

modelfun = 'y ~ k*x^2+b'

mdl = fitnlm(tb,modelfun,beta0)

plotResiduals(md1,'fitted')
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```